# Program doesn't return right answer(calculating min. perimeter)

Tags: python

The goal of the program is to find the minimum perimeter of a certain amount of squares(input from user). I thought my program was correct, but when I tested 11 (amount of squares) as input, it returned me 13 (minimum perimeter) instead of 14. Where could my mistake be?

```
def minimumperimeter(V):
    while V<0:
       V = int(input("How many squares are there?"))
    l = (math.sqrt(V))
    vk = l*l
    if vk == V:
       return l*4
    else:
       row = V/l
       perimeter = 2 * (l + row)
       if V % l != 0:
           perimeter += 2
           return perimeter
V= int(input("How many squares are there?"))
print(int(minimumperimeter((V))))
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you mean `while V<=0:`?

Comment: Show how you run the program, including user input. At what point do you actually enter the data? What is the data supposed to be? Minimum is the smallest element of a set. What set are you talking about?

Comment: No, only negative numbers get another input demand. If V is 0, it just returns 0.

Comment: You take an integer, do float calculations with it and then compare it with original int. The equality would be more or less random here depending on input integer.

Comment: This is how it runs:                                                                                   
How many squares are there?11
13

Process finished with exit code 0
The first thing that appears on the screen is "How many squares are there". The user types in 11 and it returns 13.

Comment: When you reach a resolution, please remember to up-vote useful answers and accept the best (even if you have to write it yourself).  This allows Stack Overflow to archive your question.

Answer (score 0):

`l = (math.sqrt(V))
    vk = l*l
    if vk == V:`
is always true, you should try:

`l = int(math.sqrt(V))
row = int(V/l)`

[image]

Comment: I've tried that before and it returned me 15, which isn't the right answer either. Thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: you need int for the row too, i edited my answer, seems to work as you desired

Comment: Yes, that worked indeed. I didn't realise I should've put int in front of the row too. Thanks a lot for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of errors.  As @Benoit has already pointed out, you need to truncate to `int` in a couple of places.  Also, you have to return a result for all paths -- your current code fails for a rectangle (e.g. 12 squares).

Here's working code for a variety of inputs:

```
import math


def minimumperimeter(V):
    l = int(math.sqrt(V))
    vk = l*l
    if vk == V:
       return l*4
    else:
       row = int(V/l)
       perimeter = 2 * (l + row)
       if V % l != 0:
           perimeter += 2

       return perimeter


for V in [1, 11, 12, 15, 16]:
    print(V, minimumperimeter((V)))
```

Output:

```
1 4
11 14
12 14
15 16
16 16
```

Comment: Yes, you're right that it didn't work with all inputs (didn't notice that). I should've used more test-cases. Thanks for helping me out!!